# How start a debug session in the simulator with previous app state

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I have a hard-to-catch error that only happend the 2 or 3 time I start my app, after a previous failure of it.

But because when I do Run&Debug from the XCode menu the app is delete from the simulator or device, I can debug it to find what is happening.

I try to attach to the process, but when I succed is too late and the app crash. I have the data of the crash, but can't make sense of it (and anyway, I want to know the trick!)

So, how I start dirty from in the xcode debug session so I can debug AFTER the first run of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of choosing "Build and Go" or "Go (Debug)" you should choose "Debug" from the "Run" menu--that will just re-run your app, but not re-install it.

Comment: I try that, but still clear the document folder.

I create a sqlite database, and store the last name of it (my app can manage several users using it).

Because obj-c permite put a array in a string datatype, somewhere in my code that happend. I don't find where, and I can't debug it...